# Extract Strings According to Two different Characters

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I'm trying to extract the strings after the position of two different characters/separators.  Below is the the data frame I am trying to work with:

PMLBM000DUZ_PMCRZ362RNZ_RNA-Seq.multiqc_original.zip

### Current Output

```
FileName                Date
ID1_Joe_RNA.file1.zip   2021-10-29
ID1_Jim_DNA.file2.zip   2021-03-29
ID1_Tim_RNA.file3.zip   2021-05-29
```

### Desired Output

```
FileName                Date       ID  Name  BioType  FileNo  Extension
ID1_Joe_RNA.file1.zip   2021-10-29 ID1 Joe   RNA      file1   zip
ID1_Jim_DNA.file2.zip   2021-03-29 ID1 Jim   DNA      file2   zip
ID1_Tim_RNA.file3.zip   2021-05-29 ID1 Tim   RNA      file3   zip
```

I've tried using dplyr and tidyverse but keep getting errors separating or subsetting:

```
DataSplit <- strsplit(file$FileName, "_")
DataSplit2 <-strsplit(DataSplit, ".")
```

or

```
gsub("\\_.*","", file$FileName)
```

not sure if I have to call then

`DataSplit[[#]]` for each column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use function `separate` from package `tidyr`:

```
df <- df |>
      tidyr::separate(fileName, into = c("ID","Name","BioType", "FileNo",  "Extension"), sep = "[_.]")
```

Comment: I get an error message, was thinking I could change "." for "_" _and then do separate command?_ 'df$FileName <- gsub("\\.", "_", df$FileName)'

Comment: Error: Must extract column with a single valid subscript.